# YUI Compressor: What are micro optimizations?

Tags: yui-compressor

YUI Compressor, in its (not very extensive) documentation states this as an option:

```
--disable-optimizations
    Disable all the built-in micro optimizations.
```

Does anyone know what this means?
What will this turn on/off?
I haven't found any documentation about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the source of JavaScriptCompressor:

[lines 548](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor.java#L548)-

```
    if (!disableOptimizations) {
        optimizeObjectMemberAccess(this.tokens);
        optimizeObjLitMemberDecl(this.tokens);
    }
```

[lines 467](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor.java#L467) -

```
/*
* Transforms obj["foo"] into obj.foo whenever possible, saving 3 bytes.
*/
private static void optimizeObjectMemberAccess(ArrayList tokens) {
```

[lines 497](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor.java#L497) -

```
/*
 * Transforms 'foo': ... into foo: ... whenever possible, saving 2 bytes.
 */
private static void optimizeObjLitMemberDecl(ArrayList tokens) {
```

So it's converting use of constant strings in `foo['bar']` to `foo.bar` and `{'bar':x}` to `{bar:x}`.

Comment: Thanks!
I'm definitely disabling those. For some reason, they make me feel a bit weird about YUI doing that to my code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want YUI doing that to your code? In JavaScript, `window.location` and `window['location']` mean **exactly** the same thing.

Comment: @Matthew use @ to address the reply, or I see the message, not Daniel

Comment: might be problematic in some cases, e.g. if you doo foo.delete, IE8 will think its a reserved js keyword (delete) and throw an error, so foo["delete"] is necesarry in IE8.

Comment: @Marcel delete is added to the list of reserved words, so won't get replaced https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor.java#L184